# How to show the selected option value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I having the issue when display the selected value in dropdown column.

code

```
 $scope.projects = [{id : 10, project_name : 'A'}];
```

ng-option

```
'<select ng-model="item.project" name="project" ng-options="project as project.project_name for project in projects">'
```

I could able to show the selected value by using `project.id as project.project_name......`

However, I would like to submit a whole object including `id` and `project_name` after submit.
I will get `id` value only if using `project.id` which is not expected result.

Comment: what is the issue here?  why does the code you posted not do what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
project for project in projects
```